# Passing data from a aspx page to a aspx popup

Tags: asp.net

Following is the scenario I am facing, I have a aspx page in which I have added my ascx user control, I also have a `<a href` control which call a js function to open a aspx popup.

when I open the popup, I need to send the data present in the ascx control to my popup. can you please guide me what method can I use to achieve this other than using session, as the data can be updated in many different places hence maintaining in session will be difficult.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with these syntaxe ( RegisterStartupScript + window.open)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "newWindow", "window.open('Test.aspx?ID=" + _cId + "','_blank','status=1,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=30,height=30);", false);
```

Comment: Sorry, missed mentioning, data i have to pass is big querystring will not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are using a js function to open the aspx popup.

then it is simple.

```
1. Read the Data from the controls of the User control by using javascript
   var variable1 = document.getElementByID("ControlId").value;
   var variable2 = document.getElementByID("ControlId").value;

2. Pass this data as query string to the next page
   window.open("http://www.w3schools.com?id=" + variable1 + "&name=" + variable2);
You can read this data from querystring from the next page
```

Comment: Hello Mohammed, you can add ClientId for your first script, if your control is asp.net control

Answer (score 0):

```
If you cant sent data as querystring , can try some other ways

1. Try to post the form to the other page using target="_blank".
   we can dynamically change the form action if needed.
OR
2. Make use of the window.opener object from the popup to read the data from controls the opener page.
  var variable1 = window.opener.getElementById("ControlId").value
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden variable in your ascx.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnId" />
```

On page load of ascx set the value to be sent to the hidden variable

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){    
    hdnId.Value = <value to be sent to pop-up>;
}
```

Register a ajax manager in the code behind.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).ClientEvents.OnRequestStart = "ajaxMngr_RequestStart;";

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

In the ajaxMngr_RequestStart() JS

```
    function ajaxMngr_SA_RequestStart(sender, args) {
            var oPatId = "<%=hdnSendPatId.Value %>";
            //add code to open the pop-up, add oPatId as part of the URL
        }
    }
```

I use Telerik, which makes helps a lot in managing pop-ups. Let me know, if this helps.

Cheers!